# Pass kubernetes service to a variable in Flask

Tags: nginx, flask

I have a Kubernetes cluster with 4 services running. One of the services is Nginx, which will act as a proxy for external and internal communications.
Another service is a flask application from where a user can login. After login the user is moved to another application written in go. I want to redirect the user back to Nginx after they login and Nginx will then proxy them to the go service.
The problem I'm encountering is how to redirect user to Nginx service. Nginx service is named simply nginx.
This is my code in python:

```
if usernamedata == None:
    print("Could not log in")   
else:
    if passworddata == password:
        print("Logged in")
        return redirect("http://{0}/user?username".format(nginx))
```

I understand that flask should be able to resolve nginx service name if it's in the same namespace?
Here's the nginx service:
`default | nginx | http://192.168.99.104:31316`

I have also tried `"http://nginx/user?username"` but that did not work either.
How can I redirect user back to nginx from flask?

Comment: I'm not sure if you have an ingress and 3 kubernetes services backing it up. Or you have one kubernetes service backed by 3 web services. Can you clarify?

Comment: I have 3 separate services serving 3 separate deployments running in kubernetes. I do not have an ingress, I plan to use nginx for this purpose.

Comment: I've also updated my question a bit to add more clarity(hopefully)

Answer (score 0):

This line `http://nginx/user?username` won't work outside the cluster unless you have configured your dns or `hosts` file. Also kubernetes does not pass external IP/port to pods. The Flask pod has access to the internal go service. But what you need is the nginx external ip.

You can hardcode the Nginx service's external IP into flask or have kubernetes pass it as an enviroment variable and then read it like.

```
...
redirect(os.envirton['EXTERNAL_IP'] + '/go_service')
...
```

And then have Nginx handle the request to the go service.

Comment: So I also have a mysql service named `mysql`. In my flask application I can connect to it by simply typing `mysql:3306` as database address and port. This service is discoverable by the app, how come nginx is not discoverable?

Comment: I have no idea since you don't show your k8s + nginx files.